# Microsoft Azure DevOps Repo: Search or filter by only repo name

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to incorporate search repos by name feature in my application but I'm unable to find those REST API's.

We are able to call this API to get repos information.
[https://dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PRO}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo}](https://dev.azure.com/%7BORG%7D/%7BPRO%7D/_apis/git/repositories/%7Brepo%7D)

for example. We have incorporated search repos of Github but unable to figure it our for azure,

I've referred this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/search/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0 but it says more about the  code search results , work item search results
and wiki search results which are inapplicable for us.

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search?apiVersion=2022-11-28#search-repositories.
[image]

Can anybody please help me out to find those API's.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have also checked the documents and network traces when trying to filter and search the repo. I'm afraid there's no such API can meet your requirements.

Every parameter you used in Azure DevOps REST API needs to be consistent with the description in the document, Azure DevOps REST API does not support custom parameters. And from the documents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP, there's no parameter to help filter by the repo name.